# ajax works correctly but error message displays on console

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

My code looks like this:

```
function removeUsers(){
  $("td.removeUser").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('color','red');
    var userId = $(this).find('span').data('user');
    console.log(userId);
    $.ajax({
      url: serverAPI + '/suspend-user',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data: {"userId": userId},
      success: function(data){
        console.log('suspend-user data', data);
      },
      error: function(err){
        console.log("in the error", err);
      }
    })
    window.location.replace( clientAddr + "/admin" );
  })
}
```

On the server side the function executes correctly. Why does the error message gets displayed on my console then?

Comment: what is the message?

Comment: the error message - "in the error"

Comment: do you also see "console.log("in the error", err);" output??

Comment: THis is the only error i see in my console

Comment: If it triggered the error function it means that the request failed. I suggest checking your url it is using to send to.

Comment: I think you should probably specify datatype in ajax

Comment: I checked it in Postman, my function executed correctly, made those changes in my db- just returns this error message through ajax

Comment: I figured the real issue! I am doing a page reload (window.location.replace) right after my ajax and this is leading to the error message! Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: do your page reload after ajax complete.  use .done(function( data ) {
    window.location.replace })  OR see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803028/refresh-page-after-ajax

Comment: setTimeout within complete worked! Thanks a lot @techLove :)